# Drop Down menu not working any idea why?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

You can have a look at the fiddle to view the code.
"http://jsfiddle.net/hTUUW/2/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing your `<li>`-s in the wrong place - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTUUW/3/)

It should wrap the submenu `<ul>`

```
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Client Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Employee Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Success Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Featured Employees</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Oh My God can't believe I just did that, Thanks